# Prepositions and seasons

Tags: prepositions

I've read inconsistent information when it comes to prepositions in the context of seasons. From what I remember, one typically uses 'in' together with seasons. For example, I think the following is correct:

> In estate mangiamo il gelato

Could one also say the following?

> D'estate mangiamo il gelato

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***In*** è la preposizione che si usa in riferimento alle stagioni, ma come osserva [L’Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/printpdf/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/uso-preposizioni):

> Analizzando nello specifico come possano essere impiegate le preposizioni *di*, *a* e *in* con i mesi dell'anno, osserviamo che la preposizione *di* assume il valore di determinazione di tempo indicando le parti del giorno ("di sera", "di notte"), i giorni della settimana ("di sabato"), ***le stagioni dell'anno ("d'estate")***  e appunto i mesi, come nell'espressione "era di maggio".

Comment: significa che posso usare sia 'in' sia 'di'?

Comment: @PejoPhylo: Sì, puoi dire sia "in estate", sia "d'estate".